# Visual Basic Sorting an Array with Data Read in from Text File

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, sorting, text-files

I'm having trouble with this:

*The btnDisplay_Click procedure should read the five names contained in the states.txt file, storing each in a five-element one-dimensional array. The procedure should sort the array in descending order and then display the contents of the array in the list box.*

With my code I can get the 5 state names to display in the list box, however they are not being sorted.

**FIRST ITERATION OF CODE (old):**

```
Public Class frmMain

Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

    'Declare an array for 5 states
    Dim strStates(4) As String

    Dim strStateName As String

    'Sort the array in descending order
    Array.Sort(strStates)
    Array.Reverse(strStates)

    'Declare variable to hold stream reader object
    Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader

    'Check if txt file exists before opening to avoid run time error/crash
    If IO.File.Exists("states.txt") Then
        'Open the file
        inFile = IO.File.OpenText("states.txt")
        'Loop instructions until end of file is reached
        Do Until inFile.Peek = -1
            'Read a line
            strStateName = inFile.ReadLine
            'Add line (state) to list box
            lstNames.Items.Add(strStateName)
        Loop
        'Close the file
        inFile.Close()
    Else
        'Show a message box telling user file can't be found
        MessageBox.Show("File does not exist or cannot be found.", "States", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

I've tried placing the sorting lines inside the loop as well. How do I get this to show the sorted array in the list box?

**SECOND ITERATION OF CODE (most current):**

```
Public Class frmMain

Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

    'Declare an array to hold all 5 states
    Dim strStates(4) As String

    'Declare variable to hold loop counts
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    'Declare variable to hold stream reader object
    Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader

    'Check if txt file exists before opening to avoid run time error/crash
    If IO.File.Exists("states.txt") Then
        'Open the file
        inFile = IO.File.OpenText("states.txt")
        'Loop instructions until end of file is reached
        Do Until inFile.Peek = -1
            'Read a line and store in array
            strStates(i) = inFile.ReadLine

            'Message box to confirm array loop is working correctly
            MessageBox.Show(strStates(i))

            'Manually increment array counter
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        'Close the file
        inFile.Close()

        'Sort the array in descending order
        Array.Sort(strStates)
        Array.Reverse(strStates)

        'Output to list box
        lstNames.Items.Add(strStates(i)) 'error thrown here

    Else
        'Show a message box telling user file can't be found
        MessageBox.Show("File does not exist or cannot be found.", "States", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are sorting the array before you put anything in it.

Comment: Yes, it would seem that the problem actually lies in getting the words from the text file into the array. I just realized the code doesn't do that (hence, there's nothing to sort). It just puts the words read by line right into the list box. I'm still working on it, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get rid of the array.  Use a `List(of string)` instead.  It will take you all of 5 minutes to learn how to use them.  One of the ways they are better is that you do not have to know how big to make them: they size themselves.  Then add `strStateName` to the list.  At the end, use the list as a datasource: `lstNames.DataSource = myNameList`.  Just be sure to declare the list outside that method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, good real world tip. Unfortunately, this is extra credit for a class assignment, so it HAS to be done using an array this way. I've managed to implement the array correctly now, I'm just having issues getting it sorted. I've edited my OP to reflect my new code. I think the sorting issues involve the fact that it's sorting based off of array index and not alphabetical letters. Still working on it.

Comment: You are doing too much in that loop.  Load the file data to the array in the loop.  Next, sort the array.  Finally, add the array elements to the listbox.  (There is no real reason for that array - you can add directly to the LB *and* sort it).

Comment: Okay, with some help from JerryM below, I've updated the code again. I added a message box to confirm the array is working correctly in the loop (it is). Now, I believe it's sorting correctly, but I'm getting an error on the line "lstNames.Items.Add(strStates(i))" index outside bounds of array. If I change the i to a number 0-4 it will display that array index's state in the list box. How do I get them all to show?

Answer (score 0):

Update the If statement:

```
If IO.File.Exists("states.txt") Then
    'Open the file
    inFile = IO.File.OpenText("states.txt")
    'Loop instructions until end of file is reached
    Do Until inFile.Peek = -1
        'Read a line and store in array
        strStates(i) = inFile.ReadLine

        'Manually increment array counter
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    'Close the file
    inFile.Close()

    'Sort the array in descending order (Next 2 lines don't work)
    Array.Sort(strStates)
    Array.Reverse(strStates)

    'Output to list box
    lstNames.Items.Add(strStates(i))

Else
    'Show a message box telling user file can't be found
    MessageBox.Show("File does not exist or cannot be found.", "States", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End If
```

Comment: This throws an error: "IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled. Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array." on the line that adds the array to the listbox [lstNames.Items.Add(strStates(i))]. However, if I replace the i with a number, like 0 through 4, it will display the corresponding state, but not all of them.

Comment: Yes, AddRange is the way to go for loading up the listbox items. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, thanks to the help of you two! for my last issue, I just added:

```
        For i = 0 To strStates.Length - 1
            lstNames.Items.Add(strStates(i))
        Next i
```

So the final working code looks like this:

```
Public Class frmMain

Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

    'Declare an array to hold all 5 states
    Dim strStates(4) As String

    'Declare variable to hold loop counts
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    'Declare variable to hold stream reader object
    Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader

    'Check if txt file exists before opening to avoid run time error/crash
    If IO.File.Exists("states.txt") Then
        'Open the file
        inFile = IO.File.OpenText("states.txt")
        'Loop instructions until end of file is reached
        Do Until inFile.Peek = -1
            'Read a line and store in array
            strStates(i) = inFile.ReadLine

            'Message box to confirm array loop is working correctly
            'MessageBox.Show(strStates(i))

            'Manually increment array counter
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        'Close the file
        inFile.Close()

        'Sort the array in descending order
        Array.Sort(strStates)
        Array.Reverse(strStates)

        'Output to list box
        For i = 0 To strStates.Length - 1
            lstNames.Items.Add(strStates(i))
        Next i

    Else
        'Show a message box telling user file can't be found
        MessageBox.Show("File does not exist or cannot be found.", "States",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: `lstNames.Items.AddRange(strStates)` is all you need to add the array.  Never be afraid to explore the list of methods for an object to see qhat else it does.